# How to convert NetFramwork 4 code to NetCore 2?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a C# project which was created using NetFramework 4.6. I want to convert it to using the NetCore 2.1.

I checked the network, and people say I can just change the **Target Framework** value in the project's properties page. But on my computer, I cannot see options for NetCore.

[image]

I already have the NetCore 2.1 SDK installed.

Is there another way to convert the project? Is there something wrong with my project that prevents it getting converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are wrong, there is no such "one step" approach.

Remember that .NET Core is not a higher version of .NET Framework, it is rather a rewrite from scratch. So it does not work like retargeting .NET Framework version form 4.0 to 4.5.

[Porting to .NET Core from .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) is a good place to get started.

Edit: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about#comparisons-to-other-net-implementations) lists some differences between .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this simply like this; because of their totally different frameworks, not different versions of same framework. You have to port your project to .net core; [there is one of the nice extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) for visual studio that generate a report for you about how portable your code is between .NET Framework and .NET Core.

This is also one of the [article](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/port-net-framework-net-standard/) about the issue that may be useful for you.